# Form Not Clearinng after submit

Tags: python, html, django

I created a booking form using Django's `modelformset_factory` and when I fill up the form and click on submit, it successfully stores data in database but there arise a problem the data from the form  doesnt clears instead it creats new form. But when I clears data from database the data from the forms clears automatically. Can somebody tell me the problems.

Here is my models.py code:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
passport = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
checkin = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
checkout = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
roomtype = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    db_table = "room_book"
```

Here is the code of views.py

```
def form(request):
BookForm = modelformset_factory(Booking, fields=(
    'name', 'address', 'nationality', 'passport', 'email', 'phnumber', 'checkin', 'checkout', 'roomtype'),extra=2)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    form.save()
form = BookForm()
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my code of form.html:

```
 <form id="mainForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

you still have the context with data in your template context. This is usually dont by calling `redirect()` after successful save. That also prevents the user from re-submitting the data in case he'd reload the page.

- you should also check if the form is valid by calling `form.is_valid()` before saving it
- if you know the request is `POST`, you don't (shouldn't) use `or None` where you pass `request.POST` and `request.FILES`

putting this all together can look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # no `or None`
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() # form is valid, save
        # form is saved, we can redirect away
        return redirect('.') # or reverse('wherever_you_need')
```